# List doesn't build up right

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, tuples

here is my script. I want to list all the "e_p" and "e_f" elements with my for loop but e_f somehow becomes a tuple and my "liste2" is only composed of the last "e_p" value given by my for loop. Thanks for helping

```
import rty as cpt
import numpy as np 
import CoolProp.CoolProp as cp
competition=cpt.rty()
import enthalpies as ent
import meteo as met

Ti = [competition.temp_liquide]

T_ext = [met.temp_journee,met.temp_max,met.temp_journee]
Teb = cp.PropsSI("T","P",met.press_journee,"H",0,ent.substance) - 273.15 

def energie_perdue(T_liquide,T_air,P,force_vent):
    v_vent = (force_vent*2) + 2 

    e_perdue_conv = ((10.45*v_vent)+(10*np.sqrt(v_vent)))*np.pi*(7.98/2)**2*np.abs(T_liquide-T_air)*8*3600

    return e_perdue_conv
def energie_fournie(T,P):
    Teb = cp.PropsSI("T","P",P,"H",0,ent.substance)
    Cap = cp.PropsSI("C","T",298.15,"P",P,ent.substance)

    rho = cp.PropsSI("D","T",273.15+T,"P",P, ent.substance)
    V = 2*np.pi*(7.98/2)**2
    m = rho*V 

    e_fournie = m*Cap*(Teb-273.15-T)
    return e_fournie, m, Cap
for i in range (0,3):

    e_f = energie_fournie(Ti[i],met.press_journee)
    liste1 = []
    liste1.append(e_f)

    e_p = energie_perdue(Ti[i],T_ext[i],met.press_journee,0)
    liste2 = []
    liste2.append(e_p) 

    dif_e = e_f[0] - e_p
    dif_T = dif_e/(e_f[1]*e_f[2])
    Tf = Ti[i] + dif_T
    Ti.append(Tf)
```

P.S enthalpies and meteo are scripts that I coded in other scripts 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Of course `e_f` is a `tuple`, it's simply the result of calling `energie_fournie`, which returns a tuple explicitly: `return e_fournie, m, Cap`. Also, your `liste1` and `liste2` lists always have the last value because you reassign empty lists and then append inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys I've figured it out finally